# Unbrick pixel device

Tags: unbricking, google-pixel

I accidentally flashed a Qualcomm rom to a Pixel device.
After which, neither does my device not boot and nor does power button work. It is most likely hard brick.

Running lsusb [shows](https://usercontent.irccloud-cdn.com/file/PBDOsl7e/IMG_20191014_204313.jpg): `"Qualcomm, Inc. Gobi Wireless Modem (QDL mode)"`

Is there any solution to fix this issue?
Someone please help me out.

[This](https://pastebin.com/XhNS1a76) is the script I ran to flash the rom.
Output printed during flash is available at [here](https://pastebin.com/KFUFcifC).

After some research on internet, I found [this](http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=266598&highlight=900e) tutorial.
Now I am able to put device in EDL mode.
On a Windows machine, I could see device under COMMS as Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 (COM11).

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Qualcomm devices come with an Emergency Downloader EDL mode which helps to recover from a hardbrick. You need a Flashtool and Qualcomm EDL drivers. In order to access EDL mode, you need to use an EDL cable or short JTAG pins inside the phone.

Comment: Hello Danish. Please go through [answer]. Answers on this site are not only written for OP but also for future visitors who might end up with the same or a similar problem. If you help out a user via email than those future visitors would not have a useful answer for them. Consider adding all the necessary information in your post by [edit]ing it. Do not worry about it getting long. That's fine.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Have noted it down.